# Accidentally ran "sudo chmod -x /*, is a fix possible?

Tags: linux, permissions, system-recovery

Im pretty new at linux and I really don't know how to fix this.

I accidentally ran

```
sudo chmod -x /*
```

Now every command I run returns a "Permission denied" even the `sudo` command. please help!

Comment: There are so many categories of "sawing the branch you are on" that could be avoided by leaving a password on the root account... root might still be able to log in a console (before any reboot is done anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to do much from that `os` because you cannot run any binaries in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/sbin/`. What you can do is make a live usb of any `linux os`, boot into the live environment, mount your root partition in the live environment at any mountpoint (say `/mnt/`), undo what you did i.e run the command `sudo chmod +x /mnt/*`, then finally reboot.

Comment: But the answer stands: without execute permission of a directory, no file within is accessible by a normal user. It can only be listed, **not opened**. See `man chmod.2`: "S_IXUSR  (00100)  execute/ **search** by owner (**"search" applies for  directories,  and  means that entries within the directory can be accessed**)" (same applies to "S_IXOTH  (00001)  execute/search by others" of course) => +1.

Comment: @Panki I said he cannot run any binaries and not that the permissions of binaries has changed

Comment: I ended up downloading a wanky live linux os like you said and ran `sudo chmod +x /mnt/*` and it worked! No issues so far and the machine is running along nicely!